# Is serialization the process of transmitting or conversion?

Tags: node.js, json, serialization

I have watched some videos about Serialization, and I am confused whether it refers to the process of converting the data, or transmitting it?

Let's say I have a node.js backend and a react frontend. The frontend needs to process some data, so it `JSON.parse({"name":"John"})` and sends it to the backend, and it `JSON.stringify(request.param)` it.

The process of parsing and stringifying is the serialization and deserialization, or is it the transmission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The process of parsing and stringifying is the serialization or deserialization?

Stringifying is serialization (aka encoding), parsing is deserialization (aka decoding).